# Firebug & Performance Question ?

Tags: php, mysql, firebug

i wanted to know somethings about the firebug,
when i try to load a page with firebug opend, it start the time lines.

what is :

waiting,
reciving,
DomContentLoaded,
Load,

mysql queries what affect from the list ? i see that more mysql queries i am adding, the reciving part is increasing.

let me paste a request that  ihave used on my core , to generate a dynamic link or content.

```
function getContent($id = '') {
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string ($id);
    $sql = 'SELECT id,post_title,post_content FROM wp_posts WHERE post_category="67" ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 1';
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());    

if (mysql_num_rows($res) !=0):
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {


    // this remove caption from wordpress, get 450 words to be used for exerpt, encode html,
    $mycontent = $row['post_content'];
    $mycontent = strip_tags($mycontent);
    $mycontent = substr($mycontent,0,250);
    $mycontent = preg_replace("/\[caption.*\[\/caption\]/", '', $mycontent); 
    $mycontent = htmlentities($mycontent);

    //encode the words for html
    $title = $row['post_title'];
    $title = htmlentities($title);

    echo '


    <<h1><a href="single.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$title.'</a> </h1>
    <div class="cssclass"> '.$mycontent.' </div>


    '; //echo
}
    else:
        echo 'This page dosnt exist.';
    endif;
} // end
```

Is any thing wrong on this code or its normal, my db is about 75.000 lines.

Thank you for reading this post.

Comment: This question is more about server-side performance and not really about Firebug.

Comment: please read the first part, thank you

Comment: Remove the quotes around 67 (if post_category in integer field in the database), implicit casting some times hurts performance. Make sure you have index on (post_category, post_date) - this is the best one to satisfy the given query. To protect from sql injection, if post_category is integer, cast $id to integer or use prepared statement.

Comment: thnx for comment, i have removed all "" from post_category , about the index thing, i am using a wordpres database, idk if it had them, where can i read how to add the index at database,  thank you

Comment: This is what i read at index section in my table, i have pasted it here at paste bin, link http://pastebin.com/ggAE4bKZ

Answer (score 1):

waiting: after sending a request to the server, this is the time spent waiting for data to start coming back

receiving: time spent receiving content

DomContentLoaded: time spent until the entirety of the DOM is availble (note, this is not all resources loaded, just the html portions, e.g. the `</html>` tag has been received/processed).

load: time until the entirety of the page, including images/scripts/css has been received/processed/loaded.

Don't worry about the receiving portion increasing. You're outputting more data, so it'll take more time to receive. That's perfectly normal.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, please can you take a look at the code i have pasted at the question, its it ok ? can it cause a high load on server ? as i said the db has 75.000 lines.

Comment: it'd only be a high load if you're retrieving all 75,000 lines each time. "high load" is a relative term anyways. This script would bring a server running on an old 386sx-16 to its knees, while a modern 2+ghz multicore cpu wouldn't even notice it had run anything.

Comment: i have a vps at hostgator.com, the lvl 7 VPS. And about 100 users looking at my website pages every second. so about 100 user /sec in total. and 8000 unique visitors / month. should i use any kind of cache ? if yes, can you suggest one please ? thnx

Answer (score 0):

Waiting is the time between when the browser sends the request and receiving any data at all from the server.

Receiving is the time actually getting data.

The reason Receiving is longer is because you're sending more data, so it's taking longer to download.  You might expect Waiting time to go up slightly too, but the time to transfer across the network is more significant than the time spent processing the data on the server.